# How to access the methods and html zones of one component from another in Angular 4+?

Tags: angular

Here is the scenario:

app.component.html got the main layout; 
say you got a RED-STICKY-HEADER at the top, 
and then you got a TOGGLING-ORANGE-SIDENAV on the left, and a STEADY- GREEN-SIDENAV on the right. ( the colors are only for reference purposes and make my question easier to follow. )

And to conclude, the app.component.html also has the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and that is to house the other components' html. Duh!

OK... I'm done with the scenario. So far, it's just an ordinary set up.

Here comes the complication in my mind and my question:

Say, you click on a link at the RED-STICKY-HEADER and this brings the component X's HTML in the middle.

Is it possible that you click on something on the component X's html, and this does an update on the GREEN SIDENAV contents? Please note that here, the URL does not change, no reloads takes place, and the only thing that happens is the fact that green sidenav content changes to something else. ( which could be an HTTP get request results being dumped in there, but this does not matter. )The jest of the question is is it possible to make a change in the areas that belong to app.component.html from another component?

If this is possible, then I will also ask whether it is also possible that I can trigger a component X method by clicking on a link at the RED STICKY HEADER.

In other words, is it possible to access and trigger the method of component X while you are on the app.component.html URL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. 
You can write a common service for RED-STICKY-HEADER 's component and middle component then make the updating variable as observable one in your common service.
please refer the code to create a object / list as observable in service.

```
 @Injectable()
 export class CommonService {
     aListWhichIsSubscribedByRedStickyHeader: Array<YourObject>;
     private subject = new Subject<Array<YourObject>>();

     // this is the method used to get the observable property
     getSubscribedVariables() {
         return this.subject.asObservable();
     }

     aMethodCalledByAnotherComponent(){
       /*modyfying the aListWhichIsSubscribedByRedStickyHeader
       property . Just assume that your middle component is calling this 
       method to save the object received from hhtp get request*/
     }

   this.subject.next(this.aListWhichIsSubscribedByRedStickyHeader); // so it will reflect in RedStickyHeader component's constructor.
 }
```

How you are going to subscribe it ? refer below code

```
  export class RedStickyComponent implements OnInit{

     aObjectList : Array<YourObject>;
     constructor(serviceCommon : CommonService){
        this.serviceCommon.getSubscribedVariables().subscribe(e => {
        let list = e;
        this.aObjectList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(list));
        })
     }

  }
```

so in this RedStickyHeader component wherever you are using the aObjectList there you will get changes. or by analyzing the object you can change anything inside this component or you can call another service from it.

Comment: You might need inject this service in component and call 'subject.next()' method inside a click event listener in component.